# Suggest an iterative method to evaluate $\sqrt[5]{a}$

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, newton-raphson

> Suggest an iterative method to approximate $\sqrt[5]{a}$. What is it's rate of convergence?

So obviously Newton's method would be a good choice.

If we define $f(x) = x^5 - a$ then we want to find what is the solution for $f(x) = 0$ is.

$$x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{x^5 -a}{5x_n^4}$$

We also know that the rate of convergence is squared.

Last thing is.. We want to validate the method does converges to the root.

We shall expect $|f'(r)| < 1$

$$f'(r) = f'(\sqrt[5] a) = 5\cdot a^{4/5}$$

but, $|f'(r)|$ can be greater than $1$ for a suitable $a$, and I was asked to suggest a bullet-proofed method (I guess) no matter what $a$ is.

What is your opinion regarding the choice of $a$ and the convergence of the method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also use $f(x)=x^3-\frac{a}{x^2}$ as equation to solve. Miraculously it will give you even order 3 convergence.

---

For the fixed point condition, you have to compute the derivative and contractivity of the fixed point function $g(x)=x-\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}$, not of the original function $f$ as $f(x)=0$ is no fixed-point equation. As one can readily find or compute,
$$
g'(x)=\frac{f(x)f''(x)}{f'(x)^2}
$$
which is zero at $x=r$ as $f(r)=0$.

Comment: Thanks! How did you come up with this choice of $f(x)$ so it miraculously answers our demands? (What is the intuition? )

Comment: Look up Halley's method, one way to get a compact formula for it is as the Newton method for $h(x)=\frac{f(x)}{\sqrt{|f'(x)|}}$, starting with $f(x)=x^5-a$ you have to divide by $x^2$, omitting the constants. Another compact formula for Halley's method is $x_+=x+2\frac{(1/f)'}{(1/f)''}$.